# How can $W^+$ boson turn an electron to a electron neutrino?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, charge, standard-model

If you look at the Feynmann Diagram of an electron capture:

[image]

The $W^+$ boson turns the electron into a neutrino. How is this possible? I thought the the boson carries the positive charge and converts the electrons into a positron. Why is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Converting an electron into a positron is a change of $2$ charge units, so a single $W$ can't do that.  When an electron and $W^+$ meet the total charge is zero, as required.

Answer (score 1):

A W+ boson will not be able to turn an electron into positron. It violates lepton number because electrons have +1 lepton number and antielectrons(positrons) have -1 lepton number. If an electron is +1 lepton number and positron is created by W+ boson then it is -1 lepton number. Lepton number is lost by 2 units. Also charge conservation is violated. Negatively charged particle can not turn into positively charged particle.